# GTK3 : gtk_window_resize() vs gtk_widget_set_size_request()

Tags: c++, gtk3

I am trying to set [initial] size of GtkWindow but nothing works except of `gtk_widget_set_size_request()` function.

```
GtkWindow* pw = …;
```

This does not work, it gets some strange size instead:

```
gtk_window_resize(pw,800,600);
```

This does not work either:

```
gtk_window_set_default_size(pw,800,600);
```

And only this

```
gtk_widget_set_size_request(GTK_WIDGET(pw),800,600);
```

works somehow - window will be shown with dimensions near 800x600. But the problem is that the function has side effect: after calling it user is not able to resize window less than that size - it sets min constrain to the window.

Any idea of how to define initial/default size of the window in GTK?

Comment: From within the gtk.css file?

Comment: Have you validated that your window creation succeeds? [gtk_window_set_default_size ()](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-set-default-size) should work without any issues. Now you have the `pygtk` tag listed, so if that is what you are using, you will need to check that documentation carefully. If I recall, there was verbiage that `gtk_widget_set_size_request` would become the preferred method, but I don't have a link for that handy, or when the push was for its use.

Comment: I don't know if this matters, but I would normally use `GtkWidget *pw = ...` and then `gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (pw), ...`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin window is created successfully as `gtk_widget_set_size_request()` at the same place works. If to replace it by `gtk_window_set_default_size()` - it does not work. 
Yet `gtk_window_move_resize()` - does not work either. I am lost in the zoo of move/resize GTK functions...

Comment: I think maybe what you want is gtk_window_set_geometry_hints().

Comment: Yes, Gtk+ can be a bit daunting with the hierarchy of Widgets, Windows, etc... I cannot explain why `gtk_window_set_default_size` won't work. I have used it without problems in Gtk+2, Gtk+3 (and haven't played with Gtk+4 yet). What OS? (it shouldn't matter, but...) I build under both Linux and Windows and `gtk_window_set_default_size()` works in both places. Do you have [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can tear apart?

Comment: See my comment about gtk_window_set_geometry_hints(). I think that must be what you're looking to do.

Comment: @David OS - Linux/Mint/Gnome, MCVE is hard to make. That is my Sciter Engine code ( https://sciter.com ). On Windows ::MoveWindow() works like a charm in the same place.

Comment: Also look into gtk_window_set_resizable (): "Sets whether the user can resize a window. Windows are user resizable by default.".

Comment: I also refer you to the examples here: https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-getting-started.html .

Comment: Linux should give no problems. I have an older editor project that shows my window setup. It's nothing you wouldn't expect and are probably already doing. For what it is worth [gtk_windef.c](https://github.com/drankinatty/gtkwrite/blob/master/gtk_windef.c). I see nothing wrong in the calls you are making.

Comment: Did you do `pw = gtk_application_window_new (app);`?

Answer (score 0):

GTK has its own philosophy on setting the size of windows and widgets.
You should set geometry hints before you set the default size.

```
gtk_window_set_default_size(pw,800,600);
```

These hints could be:

```
GdkGeometry hints;
hints.min_width = 800;
hints.max_width = 800;
hints.min_height = 600;
hints.max_height = 600;
gtk_window_set_geometry_hints( pw, GTK_WIDGET(pw), &hints, (GdkWindowHints)(GDK_HINT_MIN_SIZE | GDK_HINT_MAX_SIZE));
gtk_window_set_default_size (pw, 800, 600);
```